# Autounattend.xml - strange behaviour when CommandLine is long

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-10, unattended

Version: Windows 10 x64 1909 (Spanish) | Build: 18363.959

According to Microsoft, the limit of the `CommandLine` element is 1024 characters, but in my tests when it exceeds two hundred something characters it starts behaving strangely. Considering the same element is called `Path` when in the `Microsoft-Windows-Deployment` component I'm guessing the documentation is wrong and the actual is limit is 259 characters for both elements.

Sources:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-firstlogoncommands-synchronouscommand-commandline

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-deployment-runsynchronous-runsynchronouscommand-path

**How to reproduce:**

In the `oobeSystem` pass, add these under `FirstLogonCommands`:

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
  <Order>1</Order>
  <Description>Test</Description>
  <CommandLine>reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test1 /t REG_SZ /d &quot;cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&quot; /f</CommandLine>
</SynchronousCommand>
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
  <Order>2</Order>
  <Description>Test</Description>
  <CommandLine>reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test2 /t REG_SZ /d &quot;cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa&quot; /f</CommandLine>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

Command 1 gets added properly to registry and executed:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
    Test1    REG_SZ    cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

But Command 2 get added to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` literally:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
    Unattend0000000002{373CFC84-60AF-44A4-A316-9BECBAB1AD4B}    REG_EXPAND_SZ    reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test2 /t REG_SZ /d "cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" /f
```

`C:\Windows\Panther\UnattendedGC\setupact.log` doesn't show anything abnormal:

```
2020-08-17 19:09:39, Info                         [Shell Unattend] LogonCommands: Set command 'reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test1 /t REG_SZ /d "cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" /f' 
2020-08-17 19:09:39, Info                         [Shell Unattend] LogonCommands: Set command 'reg add HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v Test2 /t REG_SZ /d "cmd /k echo aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" /f'
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask why you dont run a .cmd or a reg import file.reg to bypass that limitation ?

Comment: I'm doing it from an USB stick so I have to do something like `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce /v Setup /t REG_SZ /d "cmd /c for %A in (D E F G H I J K L N M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %A:\unattend\Script.cmd %A:\unattend\Script.cmd [...]"` which got long. Since it's stated the limit is 1024 characters I thought it wouldn't be a problem. But I shortened it now after much frustration with it.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I came across the same issue, and — as you guessed — I determined the limit to be 259 characters. However, I think that — if percent variables are included in the command line — variable expansion can alter the effective limit. Unfortunately though, my tests didn't draw any definitive conclusions in this regard.

The following simple test demonstrates the 259 character limit:

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Order>1</Order>
    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
    <CommandLine>cmd /c ECHO This line will eventually be 259 characters long. This line will eventually be 259 characters long. This line will eventually be 259 characters long. This line will eventually be 259 characters long. This line will even > "C:\Windows\Temp\259.log"</CommandLine>
    <Description>259 characters, should produce file</Description>
</SynchronousCommand>
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Order>2</Order>
    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
    <CommandLine>cmd /c ECHO This line will eventually be 260 characters long. This line will eventually be 260 characters long. This line will eventually be 260 characters long. This line will eventually be 260 characters long. This line will event > "C:\Windows\Temp\260.log"</CommandLine>
    <Description>260 characters, should NOT produce file</Description>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

In short: the `<CommandLine>` line that is 259 characters long and attempts to write a file called `259.log` is successfully written, while the `<CommandLine>` line that is 260 characters long and attempts to write a file called `260.log` is not.

The first time I came across this problem, I was making some changes to the command lines of various post-Windows-install command invocations. Specifically, my changes were to fully-qualify the paths to the `.exe` files, and in some cases use environment variables e.g. `"%ComSpec%"` instead of `cmd`. But by increasing the character count I was unwittingly breaking things!

What was puzzling was that `<CommandLine>` lines of length less than 260 characters were still resulting in a failure to do what they were supposed to. I knew that the commands were correct, because without fully-qualifying the `.exe` files, they worked. Here's an example `<CommandLine>` line of 253 characters that fails:

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Order>3</Order>
    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
    <CommandLine>"%ComSpec%" /c FOR %I IN ("%InstallDrive%:\cfs-extras\installers\LibreOffice_*.msi") DO IF NOT DEFINED L "%WinDir%\System32\msiexec.exe" /i "%~fI" /l* "%TMP%\L.log" /qn ALLUSERS=1 CREATEDESKTOPLINK=1 QUICKSTART=1 ADDLOCAL=ALL UI_LANGS=en_GB ^&^& SET L=t</CommandLine>
    <Description>Silently install LibreOffice</Description>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

However, if I manually expand the variables then my command does exceed the 259 character limit! This might suggest that there is some pre-expansion of variables going on, before the command is run.

Another observation: I tried running [Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), filtering on e.g. process name = `cmd.exe` and I found that the `cmd.exe` commands that failed never appeared in the Procmon output.

As you found, I also found that `C:\Windows\Panther\UnattendedGC\setupact.log` reports the command ran successfully, irrespective of whether it did.

After reading your comment about running from a USB stick, it sounds like you're doing something quite similar to me. One thing that helped me was to set an environment variable for the USB drive letter. Hopefully that would then allow you to invoke scripts, rather than long command lines, as user *yagmoth555♦* commented. I set this up in the `<settings pass="specialize">` section:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Deployment" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
    xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <RunSynchronous>
        <RunSynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
            <Order>1</Order>
            <Description>Set InstallDrive environment variable</Description>
            <Path>"%ComSpec%" /c FOR %i IN (C D E F G H I J K L N M O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) DO IF NOT DEFINED InstallDrive IF EXIST %i:\cfs-extras "%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe" InstallDrive %i /M</Path>
        </RunSynchronousCommand>
    </RunSynchronous>
</component>
```

This simply checks each drive for a directory that's known to exist on the USB stick, and if it exists, it sets an `InstallDrive` environment variable to the drive letter of the drive with that directory. You can then reference `%InstallDrive%` later on in `<settings pass="oobeSystem">` commands/scripts. At the end of this section, I remove the environment variable with:

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
    <Order>7</Order>
    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
    <CommandLine>"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -command [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('InstallDrive',$null,'Machine')</CommandLine>
    <Description>Remove InstallDrive machine environment variable. Always run this last.</Description>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

...just to keep things clean and tidy.

I know it's four years since you asked your question, but I hope this answer is still of some relevance to you and potentially others who may have faced the same issue.